# SwiftUI Remove List padding fand Row spacing?

Tags: list, swiftui

i am trying to remove the spacing & padding to List row's , its not working after spending hours trying many solutions .

[image]

**List View :**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item {
    let uuid = UUID()
    let value: String
}

struct w_tasks: View {
    
    @State private var items = [Item]()
      
   
      var body: some View {
          ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                    List(self.items, id: \.uuid) {item in
                        cl_task().listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    }
                    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width )
                    .onAppear {
                      
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                        }
               
                    }
              VStack {
                  Spacer()

                  HStack {
                      Spacer()

                      Button(action: {
                          self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                      }, label: {
                          Text("+")
                          .font(.system(size: 30))
                          .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                          .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                          .padding(.bottom, 5)
                      })
                      .background(Color(hex : "#216D94"))
                      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                      .cornerRadius(25)
                      .padding()
                      .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
                              radius: 3,
                              x: 3,
                              y: 3)
                  }
              }
          }.background(Color.black)
      }
}

struct w_tasks_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        w_tasks()
    }
}
```

**Row Bite :**

```
import SwiftUI

struct cl_task: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
  
    var body: some View {
        //Swipe to custom options ,by "Jack" this option not yet available in SwiftUI
        let drag = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 25, coordinateSpace: .local)
       
                   .onChanged {
                    
                    if (self.offset.width > 0 ){  return }
                    self.offset.width = $0.translation.width
                
                   }.onEnded {
                   if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                       self.offset = .init(width: -100, height: 0)
                   } else {
                      self.offset = .zero
                   }
               }
        ZStack{
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue).offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
                .gesture(drag)
                .animation(.easeIn, value: offset)
            Text("test").foregroundColor(.white)
        }.frame(minWidth: 0,
                maxWidth: .infinity,
                minHeight: 120,
                maxHeight: .infinity,
                alignment: .topLeading
        )
    }
}

struct cl_task_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        cl_task().previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

And when i add The `List` inside `NavigationView`  the divider is showing again and i can't remove it any idea why!

[image]

Comment: why you used **DispatchQueue.main.async {** ? because you could use just **items.append(Item(value: "Item"))** to adding value. why DispatchQueue?

Comment: i did tried it to see if the divider between rows is back from the main thread or not , but its back because i added NavigationView

Comment: you can solve the issue with NOT using List, if that is okey I can help

Comment: @swiftPunk , what if the array has more than 400 elements dose this will effect the performance ?

Comment: I can solve your issue with not using List, just using ForEach, List is not flexible in changes and to be frankly we should accept what List can offer or not using it. for your answer I think for 400 elements, we should work on Lazy part, and it is not connected to using or not using List.

Comment: @swiftPunk , i will be waiting your answer then ^^ , i hope it will fix my issue and my concern is if the data become big it will not effect the memory

Comment: I think someone was faster than me in answering. if does not solve your issue, I have still my answer to post

Comment: @swiftPunk i am still waiting your answer , and i hope its solve my concern by saving the memory for big data , list will solve my concern , but i am afraid i can't use list anymore to achieve my goal :/

Comment: I am posting my answer to solve all issue that I found in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing and showing that there is no problem with massive data, I pre loaded 10_000 row. is that enough?

***your issues:***

1.you should make your Item type Identifiable, then you can put out uuid from your list or ForEach.

2.you should not gave frame size to your row, they can take max space automatically.

3.you can put your button over your View, and save some more coding, like I did.

4.you should not use CGSize for offset, because you are just working on one dimension, and CGFloat is enough.

5.you should and must use LazyVStack if your data is massive as you said 400 is to many, then use LazyVStack for sure.

[image]

---

```
struct Item: Identifiable {

  let id: UUID = UUID()
  let value: String

}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var items: [Item] = [Item]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    
                    ForEach(items) {item in
                        
                        RowView(stringOfText: item.value)
                            .frame(height: 120)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .background(Color.black)
            .onAppear() { for _ in 0...10_000 { addNewData() } }
            
            
            
        }
        .overlay(addButton, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        
    }
    
    var addButton: some View {
        
        Button(action: { addNewData() }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle").foregroundColor(Color.white).font(Font.largeTitle.weight(Font.Weight.bold)).padding()
        })
        
        
    }
    
    func addNewData() { items.append(Item(value: "item " + items.count.description)) }
}
```

---

```
struct RowView: View {
    
    let stringOfText: String
    
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.blue
            
            Text(stringOfText)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding()
        }
        .offset(x: offset)
        .gesture(dragGesture)
        
    }
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 25, coordinateSpace: .local)
            
            .onChanged {
                if (offset > 0 ){  return }
                offset = $0.translation.width
                
            }.onEnded {
                if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                    offset = -100
                } else {
                    offset = 0
                }
            }
        
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I have

[image]

The method you tried will work, but not on Lists, nest a ForEach inside of your list and then attach that modifier and you should be good. Also of course just tweak your modifiers to your liking of course.

Also, the way to get the spacing from between the list rows is setting a height limit on them. I just set 50 but again, modify as you see fit.

```
    struct Item {
    let uuid = UUID()
    let value: String
}

struct w_tasks: View {
    
    @State private var items = [Item]()
      
   
      var body: some View {
          ZStack(alignment: .leading){
           // List(self.items, id: \.uuid)
                    List {
                        ForEach(self.items, id: \.uuid) { item in
                            cl_task().listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(.init(top: 20, leading: -20, bottom: 20, trailing: -20)))
                            
                            .frame(height: 50)
                        }
                            
                    }
                    .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
                    
                    
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width )
                    .onAppear {
                      
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                            self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                        }
               
                    }
              VStack {
                  Spacer()

                  HStack {
                      Spacer()

                      Button(action: {
                          self.items.append(Item(value: "Item"))
                      }, label: {
                          Text("+")
                          .font(.system(size: 30))
                          .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                          .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                          .padding(.bottom, 5)
                      })
                      .background(Color("#216D94"))
                      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                      .cornerRadius(25)
                      .padding()
                      .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
                              radius: 3,
                              x: 3,
                              y: 3)
                  }
              }
          }.background(Color.black)
      }
}

struct w_tasks_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        w_tasks()
    }
}



struct cl_task: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
  
    var body: some View {
        //Swipe to custom options ,by "Jack" this option not yet available in SwiftUI
        let drag = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 25, coordinateSpace: .local)
       
                   .onChanged {
                    
                    if (self.offset.width > 0 ){  return }
                    self.offset.width = $0.translation.width
                
                   }.onEnded {
                   if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                       self.offset = .init(width: -100, height: 0)
                   } else {
                      self.offset = .zero
                   }
               }
        ZStack{
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue).offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
                .gesture(drag)
                .animation(.easeIn, value: offset)
            Text("test").foregroundColor(.white)
        }.frame(minWidth: 0,
                maxWidth: .infinity,
                minHeight: 120,
                maxHeight: .infinity,
                alignment: .topLeading
        )
    }
}

struct cl_task_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        cl_task().previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```